# Renormalization of Auxiliary Fields

Tags: renormalization, field-theory, sigma-models

I have the following non-linear sigma model (the base space $\mathcal{M}$ is Euclidean):
$$
\mathcal{L}=\dfrac{1}{2\alpha}\int_{\mathcal{M}}\mathrm{d}^2\sigma\ \partial^2X^{\mu}\partial^2X_{\mu}
$$
subject to the constraint $(\partial_aX^{\mu}+\epsilon_{ac}\partial_cB^{\mu})(\partial_bX_{\mu}+\epsilon_{bd}\partial_dB_{\mu})=\delta_{ab}$ , where $\mu=1,2\cdots,d$ and $a,b$ run over $1,2$. The partition function $Z$ is given by integrating over all $X^{\mu}$ **and** $B^{\mu}$ subject to the above given constraint. To enforce the constraint, I introduce a lagrange multiplier $\lambda_{ab}$, which allows me to integrate out the $X^{\mu}$ and $B^{\mu}$ fields which are now quadratic in the action to get an effective action for in just the constraint field $\lambda_{ab}$. Extremizing that action in the large $d$ limit, I get a non-zero VEV for the lagrange multiplier: $\langle\lambda_{ab}\rangle=\lambda_0\delta_{ab}$. This in turn leads to the following propagators (in the $d\rightarrow\infty$ limit):
$$
\langle X^{\mu}(-p)\ X^{\nu}(p)\rangle=\dfrac{\alpha}{p^2(p^2+m^2)}\delta^{\mu\nu}\\
\langle B^{\mu}(-p)\ B^{\nu}(p)\rangle=\dfrac{\alpha}{m^2p^2}\delta^{\mu\nu}
$$
where $m^2=2i\lambda_0\alpha>0$ is a dynamically produced mass scale. Using this, if we look at the effective $\langle\lambda_{ab}\lambda_{cd}\rangle$ propagator by virtue of propagation of the other fields, it is given by (at lowest order) by the inverse of the one-loop bubble diagrams:

[image]

where the straight lines correspond to the $\langle XX\rangle$ propagators and the dashed lines are the $\langle BB\rangle$ propagators. The first diagram is convergent in 2 dimensions while the log divergence of the second diagram does not manifestly cause any issues. The final diagram is quadratically divergent, which can be seen by simple power counting: The three point vertex ($i\lambda_{ab}\epsilon_{ai}\epsilon_{bj}\partial_iB^{\mu}\partial_jB_{\mu}$) is given by $\sim i\epsilon_{ai}\epsilon_{bj}(k_ik'_j+k'_ik_j)$ which gives us-
$$
I_{abcd}\sim\epsilon_{ai}\epsilon_{bj}\epsilon_{ck}\epsilon_{dl}\int^{\Lambda}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2q}{(2\pi)^2}\dfrac{q_iq_jq_kq_l}{q^2q^2}\sim\Lambda^2
$$
Actually, from my calculations, I get this term to be something like $\sim p^2\Lambda^2$ where $p$ is the external momenta. In order to renormalize something like this, I would be required to use a counter-term of the form $\sim (\partial\lambda)^2$, which I believe I am not allowed as that no longer performs to enforce the required constraint.

So my question then is this- How does one interpret a divergence as this? As a lagrange multiplier, $\lambda$ should not undergo any renormalization (or at least in perturbation, one should be able to set any multiplicative $Z_{\lambda}$ factors to one order by order, as the scale of $\lambda$ isn't fixed) and surely one isn't allowed any mass/kinetic/self-interaction terms just purely in $\lambda$ to begin with. In that case, how does one renormalize this divergence that is produced? Does this mean that the theory is sick and/or inconsistent? Mind you, I am not worried about unitarity or any such thing as I am not studying this model as a QFT.

Comment: Maybe the theory is simply not renormalizable under your constraint?

Comment: Well, yes, maybe. This is also what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if this is a sufficient condition for non-renormalizability.